# How can Copy and move `assets` folder data in runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have created 2 directories in the `assets` folder. 
One is android and second is window.

--assets 
            1:- android 
            2:- window

I have a few files inside in the android folder. I need to copy all of them from the android folder to the window folder at runtime. How do I do it?

Comment: read `AssetManager` docs

Comment: You simply can't move anything from/to assets folder at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The `assets` folder is read-only and cannot be modified after compilation.

You can copy your files into a similar structure on the internal storage if you wish to do so.